# How do I fix my CSS which works fine on Edge but doesn't on IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I'm currently working on a small webpage with a bunch of buttons with links attached to them. The webpage displays perfectly fine on Edge but I'm not sure how to fix it to make it display fine on IE. Currently the buttons and the navbar are way too big and overlapping each other.

```css
.header img {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }

  .header h1 {
    position: relative;
    top: 18px;
    left: 10px;
    font-size: 300%;
  }
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
  .container {
    display: grid;
  }

  .nav-bar {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 16.6% 16.6% 16.6% 16.6% 16.6% 16.6%;
    justify-content: space-around;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    height: 40px;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 20px;
  }

  .nav-item {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .buttons {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 16.6% 16.6% 16.6% 16.6% 16.6% 16.6%;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }

  .button-group {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  button {
    border-radius: 12px;
    background-color: gray;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    margin: 5px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  button:hover{
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
  }
  .generaldocs{
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  .technews{
    margin-left: 90px;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .nav-item a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .header a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
  }
```

Comment: We need to see a [mcve] in order to help -- we're lacking the HTML here.

Comment: By ticking check on right answer you can close the topic that could help future seekers

Comment: Only CSS code will not help us to check and reproduce the issue with IE and other browsers. We also need relevant HTML code. So that we can run it and check the result in different browsers can help us to understand the issue in better way. I suggest you to provide a proper sample code. we will again try to test it and try to provide you further suggestions. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, IE and a few old browsers required prefixes to run code correctly.

```
.header img {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }

  .header h1 {
    position: relative;
    top: 18px;
    left: 10px;
    font-size: 300%;
  }
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
  .container {
    display: grid;
  }

  .nav-bar {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 16.6% 16.6% 16.6% 16.6% 16.6% 16.6%;
    -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
    justify-content: space-around;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    height: 40px;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 20px;
  }

  .nav-item {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .buttons {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 16.6% 16.6% 16.6% 16.6% 16.6% 16.6%;
    -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }

  .button-group {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  button {
    border-radius: 12px;
    background-color: gray;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    margin: 5px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  button:hover{
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
  }
  .generaldocs{
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  .technews{
    margin-left: 90px;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

  .nav-item a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .header a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
  }
```